# How do I silence Whatsapp notifications?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp

I wanted to know if there is any way I can silence it, meaning I don't want my phone to buzz every time I receive a message, this feature was present in my previous phone ( android ).

Is this possible in windows 8 phone ?

Comment: Do you want to cancel the whatsapp notifications?  Or do you still want to receive them but not have it buzz.

Comment: @JoeHealy I want to receive them but not have it buzz.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change WhatsApp notification tone?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/how-to-change-whatsapp-notification-tone)

Comment: Whatsapp has a muting feature for group conversations. But that applies to only group conversations...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatsapp uses the toast notification feature in Windows Phone.

It uses less battery by receiving a push notification from the Server to show a notification in your phone when you app is not running at all.

As an workaround in this case you can only disable this buzz by disabling the "all other notifications" in "ringtones+sounds".

**Edit**

With the ***Windows Phone O.S. 8.1*** is possible to disable such kind of notification. Follow this steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. notifications+actions
3. Find the app you want to change the way notifications work
4. Just change the "Notification sound" to "none". Optionally you can disable the banner too in the checkbox you will find just above.