# How to change WhatsApp notification tone?

Tags: settings, notifications, whatsapp, ringtone

WhatsApp for Windows Phone is unplesant for many reasons.!

Here is another reason for this. I tried changing the system's default tone to a custom tone. It does work for other notifications. But for WhatsApp whenever I get a notification, the default tone is heard.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Changing the notification tone and making the notification silent, are two different aspects, i guess. :)

Comment: I get to manage WhatsApp in there. I can even silent it and I can even change its default tone to something I want. :)

Comment: The worst things is I cant see any third party application under 'notification+action'. So I cant see WhatsApp as well. I resolution to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**settings** > **ringtones+sounds** > **manage app sounds** at the bottom. I think you should see appropriate app sound to change.
Note this only works in Windows Phone 8.1,

Comment: What about Windows Phone 8?

Comment: There is no way to change this in Windows Phone 8. But if you want to upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1, this link could help you: http://www.wpcentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers

Comment: Or even this link: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3479/106

Comment: @VivekParekh The only way to change the notification sound before 8.1 is if the app provides this functionality (after GDR3)

Answer (score 2):

There is another path to the same set of configs:

With the ***Windows Phone O.S. 8.1*** follow this steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. notifications+actions
3. Find the app you want to change the way notifications work
4. Just change the "Notification sound" to the appropriate sound you want.

Comment: Your answer brings the same thing as the already accepted one.

Comment: Thanks @Potek. I didn't know we could arrive in the same settings. I admit I overlooked the answer and thought it was about remove the notifications entirely (not just the one OP wanted).

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that this is a way to do the same thing. Thanks for the heads up.